# Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line) in ESRI's display a map tutorial

Tags: kotlin, arcgis-android-api, microsoft-appstudio

So Android Studio is a new development environment for me and I am working through ESRI's tutorial on how to display a map using kotlin.  The tutorial can be found here:

https://developers.arcgis.com/kotlin/maps-2d/tutorials/display-a-map/

I am setting up the gradle files according to the tutorial, but when I sync I get the following error: "Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)"

Here is the block of code that is causing the problems:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven{
            url "https://esri.jfrog.io/artifactory/arcgis"
        }
    }
```

Could someone provide insight as to why I am getting the error?

I expected the gradle to sync without errors, but I do not understand this error code.

The error code indicates that it is the url line that is causing the difficulties.

After trying Jorn's suggestion, I got a few more errors including the original.

- Function invocation'uri(...)expected
- No value passed for parameter 'path'

Comment: You are using Groovy syntax in a Gradle (Kotlin) file. Try `url = uri("https://esri.jfrog.io/artifactory/arcgis")`

Comment: I will give this a try when I get home tonight.